# Totally new to Talend ESB

Tags: esb, talend

I'm completely brand new to Talend ESB (not so much Talend for data integration, but ESB totally.)

That being said, I'm trying to build a simple route that watches a specific file path and get the filename of any file dropped into it. Then it will pass that filename to the childjob (cTalendJob) and the child job will do something to the file.

I'm able to watch the directory, procure the filename itself and System.out.println the filename. but I can't seem to 'pass' it down to the child job. When it runs, the route goes into an endless loop.[image]

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I also understand that this is obtainable outside of ESB, but for scalability reasons and job isolation, I found ESB to be a good fit for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a context parameter to your Talend job, and then pass the filename from the route to the job by assigning it to the parameter.
In my example I added a parameter named "Param" to my job. In the Context Param view of cTalendJob, click the + button and select it from the list of available parameters, and assign a value to it.

[image]

You can then do context.Param in your child job to use the filename.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the response. However, my issue is the directory will have a multitude of files and I need to dynamically set the "value" for the Param, as you depict above. I have the file name, through the following in the cProcessor 
    `context.body =((String)exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));`. I then attempt to wrap it in xml tag like so. 
    `context.FileHandle = "<body> + context.body + "</body>"`. In the child job, I simply try to 
    `System.out.println(context.body);` to no avail.

Comment: But if i go straight from a tRouteInput (with schema of "body") to a tLogRow, it spits out the content of the file, not just the name of the file.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry I don't have access to my computer right now in order to check this. I will have it on monday, I hope someone answers your question by then, else I'll write back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this more difficult than you need...

I don't think you need your cProcessor or cSetBody steps.

In your tRouteInput if you want the filename, then map `"${header.CamelFileName}"` to a field in your schema, and you will get the filename. Mapping `"${in.body}"` would give you the file contents, but if you don't need that you can just map the required heading. If your job would read the file as a whole, you could skip that step and just map the message body.

Also, check the default behaviour of the camel file component - it is intended to put the contents of the file into a message, moving the file to a .camel subdirectory once complete. If your job writes to the directory cFile is monitoring, it will keep running indefinitely, as it keeps finding a "new" file - you would want to write any updated files to a different directory, or a filename mask that isn't monitored by the cFile component.